# Why is the Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer extension not working for VS Community 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, vdproj

We have been using vdproj to build msi for our executables. 
We have been using this in VS2017 without issue until a recent update caused an error in VS2017 that required a reinstall. 
Since the reinstall, the vdproj files are no longer able to load after also installing the installer located here.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects

Here is a snapshot showing that the package is in fact installed, and the projects are not loading.
[image: no go]

Any insight into what we may need to change in the registry/etc. to get this working again?

Comment: Have you restarted Visual studio?

Comment: @Anthony McGrath
many times and rebooted.

Comment: You could trying manually removing the relevant programs and then reinstalling them.  The directions in this link http://jermsmit.com/uninstall-of-sql-fails-with-error-about-rsfx-driver/ I have used before to fix visual studio program install issues.

Comment: @Anthony McGrath I probably won't ask customers to do that, which is who needs the installers.